# Wordpress Images Some showing some are not

Tags: wordpress

My website is comugg.com. On my site most of my pictures are showing properly. But a set of pictures i added not too long ago dont load properly or show properly.

here is a example of one that works properly
http://comugg.com/fordtruck-angleview/

here is a example of one that doesnt work properly
http://comugg.com/fordfusion-43/

If anyone could start me off on the right direction to fix this i would appreciate it.

Comment: image tag is missing in your second link. can you post your code?

Comment: theres no code? i didnt edit any code or anything

Comment: can you post the html from admin editor?

Comment: ah i think i fixed the problem. thanks for your help. I used a plugin that forced the regeneration fo all my images. did the trick